# Workflow Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate, microsoft365

I have a Sharepoint list with a "Date" column and a "Money pot" column.
I would like to create a Power Automate feed so that when the date is more than 3 years old, we add the value "300" in the "Money pot" column. But I don't know at all how to do that.
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to set up a flow that runs every so often - weekly, maybe.
The flow would check the Date against today, and if it was >= 3 years (1095 days) AND the MoneyPot column was empty, then update MoneyPot to 300.

Date>=3 years AND MoneyPot = 0: MoneyPot = 300

If it needs to be +300 every 3 years...

MoneyPot = (Integer((Today-Date)/365)/3)*300